# How shouild I save model weights in Pytorch?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

```
### Create / load model

# Faster - RCNN Model - pretrained on COCO
model = torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True)
num_classes = 2

# get number of input features for the classifier
in_features = model.roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.in_features

# replace the pre-trained head with a new one
model.roi_heads.box_predictor =  FastRCNNPredictor(in_features, num_classes)
```

Training the model doesn't use `model.fit()` function, it uses cycles.

```
    # let's train it for 10 epochs
    num_epochs = 10

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        # train for one epoch, printing every 10 iterations
        train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, data_loader, device, epoch, print_freq=10)
        # update the learning rate
        lr_scheduler.step()
        # evaluate on the test dataset
        evaluate(model, data_loader_test, device=device)
```

How can I save the model?

Comment: That seems like Pytorch, not Keras.

Comment: In Pytorch, it is done following the method [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#save-load-state-dict-recommended).

Answer (score 1):

PyTorch has a `state_dict` which stores the state of the model (in this case, the neural network) at any point in time. Saving it would involve dumping those states into a file which is easily done with:

```
torch.save(model.state_dict(), PATH)
```

When reloading the model, remember to first create the model class with its default weights and load the state dict from the file.

Here's a link to saving/loading pytorch modules (https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html).